# Gain access to query parameters via React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have seen several posts that say you should reference this.props.location to gain access to the query string parameters.  However, whereever I check this property, location is always 'undefined'.  I am missing something obviously.

Here is my setup...

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Lender.Services.Web",
  "homepage": "/dataexchange/lender",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-grid-system": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
import './index.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href');
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl}>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  rootElement);

registerServiceWorker();
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NewRequest } from './components/NewRequest';

export default class App extends Component {
    displayName = App.name

    render() {
        return (
            <NewRequest />
        );
    }
}
```

If I break in App.js in the render function, the this.props.location is undefined.

How do I gain access to the query string parameters with my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React router only injects the route props to components it routed to. Now your `App` component is not getting routed to via react router, it simply getting rendered as the top level component.

```
<BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl}>
    <App />
 </BrowserRouter>,
```

If you want react-router to inject the route params, you need to actually have a route which leads to the `App` component. Something like this.

```
<BrowserRouter basename={baseUrl}>
    <Route path={"/"} exact component={App} />
 </BrowserRouter>,
```

Now when you go the `/` route in the browser you will see `App`, but if you go elsewhere you will not, this is because now react-router is rendering your component when the path matches, and when it renders it, it will also inject the route props to it.

Comment: Or you can use the [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HOC to inject the router props into `App`

Comment: Also it should be `this.props.history.location` not `this.props.location` as OP mentioned in the question.

Comment: That is absolutely correct, but to me `withRouter` is used to inject route props to a child component, or another component which would not normally get router props, but here, the `App` component can just be made the routed to component and there is no need for `withRouter`.

Comment: @devserkan thats true, but the issue was the routing props simply didn't exists, and now they do, and now its just a question of correct syntax.

Comment: Yes. I was going to write an answer but you've done it before. Then I just want to remind the true syntax in case of OP don't know it.